# Speech Synthesizer C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem in using this speechsyntesizer in c#. Im creating a project called quiz game inspired by who wants to be a millionaire. Now what I want to do is everytime the computer read the question by using speakAsync the timer will stop and it will resume after it read all the choices. And also the choices are hidden it will show only after the computer read it. But it seems like Im on the wrong path. The timer resume and the choices are already revealed everytime i run the program. Here is my code:

```
    timer1.Stop();

            voice = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            voice.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Child);

            twodip = 1;
                btnA.Visible = false;
                btnB.Visible = false;
                btnC.Visible = false;
                btnD.Visible = false;
                btn50.Enabled = true;
                btndoubledip.Enabled = true;

                lblQuestion.Text = (string)reader["Question"];
                voice.SpeakAsync(lblQuestion.Text.ToString());

                btnA.Text = (string)reader["A"];
                voice.SpeakAsync(btnA.Text);
                 btnA.Visible = true;

                btnB.Text = (string)reader["B"];
                voice.SpeakAsync(btnB.Text);
                btnB.Visible = true;

                btnC.Text = (string)reader["C"];
                voice.SpeakAsync(btnC.Text);
                btnC.Visible = true; 

                btnD.Text = (string)reader["D"];
                voice.SpeakAsync(btnD.Text);
                 btnD.Visible = true;




                ans = (int)reader["Answer"];


            timer1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an async method while trying to synchronous work. Change the method from SpeakAsync to Speak and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you dude! It work perfectly but theres something wrong Im lagging when using Speak instead of SpeakAsync dunno why :/ but it perfectly work as expected

Comment: Not sure what you mean by lagging the UI is frozen? Text box isn't visable quickly?